# unable to update profile picture using varbinary

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, file-upload, varbinarymax

I'm trying to update my profile picture using varbinary (SQL Server 2008). It don't seem to update the picture that I put in the fileupload. Below is the code I use to update my profile picture. Do help me take a look on which part of my coding did I do wrongly.
Thanks.

```
protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String username = (String)Session["username"];

        string filePath = FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName;
        string filename = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
        string ext = Path.GetExtension(filename);

        string contenttype = String.Empty;

        switch (ext)
        {
            case ".jpg":
                contenttype = "image/jpg";
                break;
        }
        if (contenttype != String.Empty)
        {
            Stream fs = FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream;

            BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);

            Byte[] bytes = br.ReadBytes((Int32)fs.Length);

            //insert the file into database
            string strQuery = "Update LoginRegisterOthers Set profilepic = @Data Where username = '" + username + "'";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Data", SqlDbType.Binary).Value = bytes;
            InsertUpdateData(cmd);
            lblMessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
            lblMessage.Text = "Profile Updated.";

            Response.Redirect("MemberProfile.aspx");
        }
        else if (contenttype == String.Empty)
        {
            lblMessage.Text = "Please select your image before uploading!";
        }
        else
        {
            lblMessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            lblMessage.Text = "File format not recognised." + " Upload Image formats";
        }
    }

  private Boolean InsertUpdateData(SqlCommand cmd)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=localhost; Initial Catalog=project; Integrated Security=True");
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Connection = con;
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.Message);
            return false;
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
            con.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should use a **parameter** for your user name in that `UPDATE` query, too!

Comment: @marc_s It still don't work even if I use parameter for username.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
...

//insert the file into database

string strQuery = "Update LoginRegisterOthers Set profilepic = (SELECT BULKCOLUMN FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'"+filename+"',  SINGLE_BLOB) AS FIle_picture)  Where username = '" + username + "'";

...
```

You can load a file directly with sql.